# How to wire L1, L2, n1, n2 and pe wires to install 220v-240v stove?

Tags: wiring, stove, voltage

[image]

I'm trying to install a stove but I'm stuck on the wiring. There's an l1, l2, n1, n2 and pe wire sticking out of the wall. The stove has four attachment points for the wires. I don't know how to attach the wires in order to make it 220-240 volts. How am I supposed to wire it?

Comment: Is this for the US or you in another part of the world?

Comment: It appears the applicable connections are shown in the upper right diagram. So it would appear you only would need 3 of the wires in the cord: L1, N and PE.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  Also, do you have a manual for this stove? (I can't find anything on the Internet about it O.o)

Answer (score 1):

None of the drawings in pic 2 want 2 neutrals.  So the relevant  lineside wiring in pic 4  is the one your hand is covering, with black-brown as two hots, and gray as 1 neutral.

Now we need to sanity-check our power requirements for the stove.  The stove lists its max power as 7kw.  That is 30.4 amps at 230V.  Two 16A hots can just feed that, if the loads are balanced in the machine.

Now there is only one wiring diagram in pic 2 that wants L1-L2-N-PE.  That is the drawing on the lower left.